# How to efficiently determine the `name` field of an sobject for dynamic query?

Tags: apex, performance, describesobject, describefieldresult

Is there a more efficient way to determine the **name** field of an sobject other than iterating through all the fields obtained via DescribeSOBjectResult?

Often, the name field is simply `Name` but in some occasions with standard objects it is not. For example, Case's name field is `CaseNumber`.

Here is the apex method I'm using, but seems inefficient to loop through all the fields:

```
public String getNameField( SObjectType sobjectType ) {

    DescribeSObjectResult objDescribe = sobjectType.getDescribe();

    Map<String, SObjectField> fieldsMap = objDescribe.fields.getMap();

    for ( SObjectField fieldToken : fieldsMap.values() ) {

        DescribeFieldResult fieldDescribe = fieldToken.getDescribe();

        if ( fieldDescribe.isNameField() ) {
            return fieldDescribe.getName();
        }

    }

    return 'Name'; // default
}
```

Comment: You could do the describe for the `Name` field first and only check all fields if that isn't it. More efficient (on average) but not very elegant...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Elegant? Perhaps not, but checking `'Name'` first and only iterating as a fallback plan should be more efficient. With every custom object and most standard objects, this shortcut will cut out the looping and additional describes entirely.

My natural inclination is to start with a positive condition:

```
public static String getNameField(SObjectType sObjectType)
{
    Map<String, SObjectField> fields = sObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
    if (fields.containsKey('Name') && fields.get('Name').getDescribe().isNameField())
    {
        return 'Name';
    }

    // iteration logic

    return 'Name'; // fallback if iteration fails
}
```

It may be more elegant, however, to use a negative condition and DRY on the `return 'Name'` front.

```
public static String getNameField(SObjectType sObjectType)
{
    Map<String, SObjectField> fields = sObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
    if (!fields.containsKey('Name') || !fields.get('Name').getDescribe().isNameField())
    {
        // iteration logic
    }
    return 'Name';
}
```

Comment: In the event `Name` field was not actually, well, the naming field, should the if condition be `if ( fields.containsKey( 'Name' ) && fields.get( 'Name' ).getDescribe().isNameField() ) { return 'Name' } else { ... iteration logic ... }` ?

Comment: I'm getting foggy on my boolean logic here with negative || vs. positive &&. Might be the same thing, but the way you have it guarantees a final return statement at the end for compilation.

Comment: But then you also `return 'Name'` if the iteration fails to find one. Hence using this condition, you only have to `return 'Name'` once in your code. Since you asked for a more elegant solution, I considered this inversion of the condition more so.

Comment: Good point, and the odds that a standard `Name` field isn't a naming field is probably nil. Thanks!

Comment: Another reason not to loop through looking for `isNameField` is that when you have Person Accounts enabled, the `Account` object fields `FirstName`, `LastName` and `Name` all have `isNameField` true. Chances are you want `Name`!

Answer (score 6):

A little late to the party, but SOQL could help here too:

```
SELECT QualifiedApiName
FROM FieldDefinition
WHERE EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName IN :listOfSObjectNames
AND IsNameField = TRUE
```

It does consume one query but that is probably more efficient than looping through describes.

Comment: Not too late for me! This is perfect for the situation I just found myself in :)