# How to get all the field names and data type of each field using Dynamic SOQL with Lookups?

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, dynamic-soql

I am trying to get the Datatype, Label, and SObject of fields in a Dynamic SOQL Query.

For Example, I have the following objects that are called in the below SOQL Query:

- "Product_User__c"
- "Product_Organization__c"
- "Account"
- "Contact"
- 

```
String Query =   "SELECT ID, Product_Organization__r.Number_Of_Logins__c, Product_Organization__r.Account__r.Domain, Product_User__r.Contact__r.LastName  FROM PRODUCT_DATA__C"
```

For each field in this query, I want to be able to get the following information:

- Datatype
- Field Label
- SOBject Name
- Salesforce ID of Lookup
- Record "Name" of Lookup (This would be "CaseNumber" for Cases, "Name" for Accounts, etc. )

Below is the preliminary code I have started writing, but I am struggling to be able to get the object of the custom field lookup.

```
Map <String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMapofAllSobject = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
Map <String, Schema.SObjectField> MapofdesiredObject = schemaMap.get('Contact').getDescribe().fields.getMap();
for(Schema.SObjectField sObjectfield : MapofdesiredObject.Values())
{
schema.describefieldresult dfield = sObjectfield.getDescribe();
system.debug(‘@@@API Name : ‘  + dfield.getname());
system.debug(‘####Label Name : ‘ + dfield.getLabel ());
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "ID of Lookup" and "Record Name of Lookup"?

Comment: @AdrianLarson I am referring to the "Salesforce Record ID" and the "Standard Name" field on the record. For example for Cases this would be "CaseNumber" or for Accounts this would be the standard "Name" field

Comment: The Id field is always `Id`. As for `Name`, see [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/149790/2995).

Comment: @AdrianLarson Thank you - Now I just need to figure out how to get the Data Type of the field along with its SObject. I am thinking that I need to get the ID first of the lookup and I can do that by check if there is a "." in the lookup. From there I can query the ID to get the Sobject Describe information.